# Use SharePoint Client Components SDK with Microsoft Office vba (Powerpoint, Access)

Tags: vba, ms-access, sharepoint, components, client

For a proof of concept I would like to do the following:

1. Iterate over a subset of powerpoint files on a secure sharepoint (https, windows authentication), subset created based on meta data e.g. author, upload date
2. Open the powerpoint files and store the text information in a database
3. Perform certain text analysis functions, e.g. word cloud on action titles

For the proof of concept I would prefer to simply use MS Access and SharePoint Server 2013 Client Components SDK:

- https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=35585
- http://achildstechnologyblog.blogspot.it/2013/07/develop-client-applications-for.html

Unfortunately when I try to add the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll as a reference to the VBA editor I receive a ("can't add a reference to the specified file") message. 
Sorry for my greenly approach but any possibilities to get around a heavy visual studio installation for the proof of concept?

Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because dll files are for C# projects. Try move your application to Office add-in. There is a special project for this in Visual Studio  called PowerPoint 2013 (or 2010) Add-in.